# What connects the Welsh and English Gogmagog with the Hebrew Gog and Magog?

Tags: folklore, welsh, giants, eschatology, jewish

The guardian statues outside London's Guildhall, the building that houses the administration of the Corporation of the City of London, are known as Gog and Magog. Originally they were understood to be of [Gogmagog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gogmagog_(giant)), the giant of Welsh and English folklore, and [Corineus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corineus), a Trojan warrior, associate of Brutus, and fighter against giants.

[Gog and Magog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gog_and_Magog) were two entities who appear in the Book of Ezekiel and Jewish eschatology.

What is the connection between Gogmagog the giant and Gog and Magog the entities referenced in the bible? The idea that there is no connection surely seems far-fetched.

Comment: The Gogmagog (and variants) of Brittanic folklore is of course based on the Gog and Magog of the Bible.

Comment: So you don't go along with the opinion expressed by Manley Pope, translator of Geoffrey of Monmouth's *Historia Regum Britanniae*, and by others, that "Gogmagog" derives from "Gawr Madoc" meaning "Madoc the Great"? How did a giant acquire a name that combined the names of Gog and Magog?